# In 1 Chronicles 22, is David lying when he says that the Lord said that he was barred from building the house of God because he was a man of war?

Tags: david, 1-chronicles

1 Chronicles 22:6-11 (KJV)

> 6 Then he called for Solomon his son, and charged him to build an house for the Lord God of Israel.
> 7 And David said to Solomon, My son, as for me, it was in my mind to build an house unto the name of the Lord my God:
> 8 But the word of the Lord came to me, saying, Thou hast shed blood abundantly, and hast made great wars: thou shalt not build an house unto my name, because thou hast shed much blood upon the earth in my sight.
> 9 Behold, a son shall be born to thee, who shall be a man of rest; and I will give him rest from all his enemies round about: for his name shall be Solomon, and I will give peace and quietness unto Israel in his days.
> 10 He shall build an house for my name; and he shall be my son, and I will be his father; and I will establish the throne of his kingdom over Israel for ever.
> 11 Now, my son, the Lord be with thee; and prosper thou, and build the house of the Lord thy God, as he hath said of thee.

David declares to his son Solomon that he has been barred from building the house of God because he was a man of war. In verse 9, David states the the vision actually names Solomon directly. If you read the vision (2 Samuel 7) that Nathan had concerning the temple, we see there was no mention of Solomon nor any mention of David being a man of war.

Is David lying or was he just embelishing God's word because he was sincerely mistaken about the application of the vision?

Answer (score 2):

First, 2 Sam 7 and 1 Chron 22 are discussing different events that were many years apart:

**2 Sam 7** immediately follows the bringing of the ark and tabernacle to Jerusalem at the height of David's power and authority.  2 Sam 7 relates the establishment, by God, of the Royal Davidic Covenant involving an eternal throne.  This was fulfilled by Jesus (later revealed by be through Solomon) as per Luke 1:33-35, 49, Rev 11:15, etc.

**1 Chron 22** is part of the narrative of 1 Chron 21 (see 1 Chron 22:1) about the sin of David taking a census (and its consequences) and thus is parallel to 2 Sam 24.  According to 1 Chron 22, David received several instructions about the construction of the temple:

- V8 - David had too much blood on his hands to build the temple and so could not build the temple
- V9 - David was promised son who would not be a man of way, hence his name, "Solomon".
- V10a - Solomon, the promised son of peace, would build the temple
- V10b - Solomon would inherit the Royal/Davidic covenant promises of the Royal king, Messiah, to come as per 2 Sam 7:12-14.

Thus, there is no conflict to deal with between these two passages.  That is, the revelation given to David in 1 Chron 22 was in addition to 2 Sam 7.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I don’t believe your answer harmonizes all of scripture. First, there is grammatical support for the word “Spirit” in 1 Chron 28:12 to be David’s spirit and not the Holy Spirit. Also, context of Steven’s speech in Acts 7 from v39 on uses the same language and argument that God uses in 1 Samuel 7, where God asks David when did I ever ask anyone to build me a house. There is too much evidence to suggest that David acted on his own desire.

Comment: @ab - first, I did not quote 1 Chron 28:12 - I agree with your comment above about the spirit.  However, the fact that God told David these things does not alter that David had a vast plan in mind; that is, the Holy Spirit did NOT inspire every detail of the construction - most was David's idea.  So I do not see how the two conflict at all.